# ant build successful but not compiling jsp files

Tags: ant, weblogic

I'm using ant1.7.1 in weblogic server 10.3.3 for compiling java and jsp files. It will create a EAR and I'll deploy it in test/prod server, while deploying it, it will explore the files with build date, but now when i build, this gives class files with build date but not jsp files, jsp files have the same date as modified. But build is successful.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the weblogic ant task (weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.AppC) to pre-compile jsps?

Comment: No i'm not using ant task.